# Adjusting height of v-list-tile in Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/mikecole/pen/NBgmvN)

Relevant section is:

```html
<v-list-tile>
  <v-list-tile-content>
    <div>
      This is some content that's a little tall.<br />
      Maybe there's a lot of stuff that goes here.<br />
      Or maybe I'm using a third party control.<br />
      Either way, how can I adjust the height?
    </div>
  </v-list-tile-content>
</v-list-tile>
```

I have a Vuetify menu that contains a list. One of the list items is taller than the 48px set in the base styles. Is there a way to adjust this gracefully in the markup? Or do I need to use css to adjust?

Comment: just fyi - vuetify have a discord channel where devs of vuetify ( as well as not devs) help to solve such questions.

Comment: I've posted a few questions there with no response. I can cross post this there.

Comment: You need to use css. Or you can try with `<v-list three-line>`.

Comment: Any tips on how I can reliably target a single v-list-tile (the last one)? I can't seem to append an ID or a custom class to the component itself.

Answer (score 8):

According to the docs, you can increase the size of items in [`<v-list>`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists#api) with either `two-line` or `three-line`

[image]

Beyond that, it's advised you use a card:

> For three line lists, the subtitle will clamp vertically at 2 lines and then ellipsis. If you need more than 3 lines, it is advised to use a [card](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/cards).

The purpose of v-list is to enforce uniformity of height in repeated elements, so if you need more than three lines to convey a particular point, it probably makes sense to use a repeating card element that can cover more area and use cases.